# Magento: how do I determine if a customer is new?

Tags: magento

I want to be able to send different order confirmation emails to new customers than to established customers.

I am already able to put a block in the email template to insert my own *'if'* constructs based on order details.

I can get the customer data from the order id, e.g. the customer id, but how can I determine if they are a new customer?

Even if it is getting the customer creation date and checking if it is less than five minutes, I need a technique to determine if they are new from within my template code based on the order information.

Comment: Would a customer with no previous orders be considered as "new"?

Comment: Definitely - if you have any insights please share!

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31853/how-to-know-if-an-order-is-from-existing-customer-or-new-customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way your going to just have to do calculations on `created_at` field in the `customer_entity` table. If not your going to have to find some specific window to consider customers as "new".

Don't think I'd put said logic in the template file but rather a model and just pass it a block to flag it or not.

Comment: Voting -1 because it's really bad approach. I would not recommend to use created_at as real indicator that customer is really new.